# Firebase App Check for Web App not working, did follow instructions, where am I going wrong?

Tags: javascript, firebase-realtime-database, firebase-app-check

So I followed the instrucutions on adding Firebase App Check as listed [here](https://firebase.google.com/docs/app-check/web/recaptcha-provider?authuser=0&hl=en). I created a reCAPTCHA V3 project and copied the "Use this site key in the HTML code your site serves to users." in my firebase Init and then copied the "Use this secret key for communication between your site and reCAPTCHA" onto App Check setup (project/../settings/appcheck). I still am getting all unverified requests. Am I missing something? what am I doing wrong?

My init code is below:

```
    import firebase from 'firebase/compat/app'
    import 'firebase/compat/app-check'
    import 'firebase/compat/auth'
    import 'firebase/compat/analytics'

        // setting of firebase config params

        export const firebaseApp = firebase.initializeApp(config)
        if (firebaseApp) {
          const appCheck = firebase.appCheck()
          appCheck.activate('the HTML key from reCaptcha')
        }
```

I am not getting any errors in console. How do I debug this?
[image]

Comment: Maybe you should be sure that everything is mounted in the page before running the method? I mean, couldn't the function be called before you effectively have the runtime of firebaseApp?